# Composer showing xdebug enabled after commenting out zend extension

Tags: composer-php, wampserver, git-bash

I have installed WampServer and Composer Dependency Manager.

In git bash, when I execute `composer -v`, I get the following warning message:

"You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug"

As instructed in the provided url, I have commented out zend extension in my php.ini file and saved it.

My php.ini file now has the following relevant lines:

```
;zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

Then I stopped and started all wamp services. Restarted git bash and executed `composer -v`. But I am still getting the same warning message. Why is it still showing? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you edited the wrong ini file, being used by Apache instead of the CLI. Run this command in a command prompt:

```
php --ini
```

It will show you exactly which ini file needs to be edited to remove xdebug from CLI invocations.